# Changing AxesStyle for 3D plots to include arrowheads on the axes

Tags: plotting

I like to have arrowheads on my plots.  For example,

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.05]]
```

This puts arrowheads on the ends of the positive axes.  However, I have tried the same option in Plot3D and it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.05]]
```

Is there a way to add this functionality as an option to Plot3D?  Otherwise it seems like I have to manually create and add in the arrows at their exact positions, which is pain, especially if I want to change the range of my plot.  I have to move the arrows individually.  It seems like there must be a better way.

Comment: @Kuba  AxesEdge doesn't seem to answer the question as I am asking how to include arrows on the axes in Plot3D.   AxesEdge just allows me to change which axes to include in the bounding box.

Comment: Right, sorry, missed your point.

Comment: @Kuba, it seems this question will be closed as a duplicate, but in the linked question, the accepted answer doesn't actually show how to add the arrows to a `Plot3D`.  In order to apply Jens's function to a general `Plot3D`, all three axes would need to be the same length, and some trial and error is needed to find that length.

Comment: @JasonB Tell this to Jens :P It doesn't change the fact that it is a duplicate. But I agree that old accepted answers are not encouraging to answer them. I think your newest question is good solution to this situation.

Comment: Wait, did you just stick out your virtual tongue at me?  The level of discourse on this site, lol.